# Removing non-English words/characters from .csv file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, export-to-csv

I've exported an IoT dataset with scraped together content from their websites into a .csv file (let's call data.csv). Some of this content is encoded in Japanese/Chinese/various European languages, and refuses to open when the program I'm importing it in detects one of these special characters.

Is there any way to use PowerShell to remove any and all non-English encodings from the csv and export it as a copy? I mean, keep a-z,A-Z,0-9, commas, question marks, brackets, etc., but remove anything that's non-English from the dataset?

I've tried saving the file as a utf-8 encoding from Notepad, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: while i have never used any of it ... the normalization stuff in dotnet can be called from PoSh. it can map chars with accents/diacritic marks, and multi-byte chars into ascii.

Comment: Are you sure it's the characters that's the problem and not just the decoding that's the problem? Which character encoding is used for the file? Can you tell that to your program? (You have to do that even when reading the file with PowerShell.) Or, could your program read xlsx or ods instead?

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression that matches by character's hex value could work. The naïve approach is to just replace any invalid character with one that works. Commonly `-` is used as such a character

As sample data, consider some nonsense CSV containing Japanese and European letters `åäöè`:

```
id,data
1,Lorem内ょへconsectetur  
2,ipsum 球経風adipiscing
3,dolor 
4,sitåäöèelit
5,amet
```

Import the file as CSV, loop through and replace each non-ASCII character with, say, a dash. The regex `[^\x00-\x7A]` will match characters that have a hex value of 00 to 122, or, `nul` to `z`. Depending on your use case, tune the range accordingly. Like so,

```
$data = Import-Csv C:\temp\mixed.csv

$data | % {
    $_.data = $_.data -replace "[^\x00-\x7A]","-"
}

$data

# Output
id data
-- ----
1  Lorem---consectetur
2  ipsum ---adipiscing
3  dolor
4  sit-----elit
5  amet
```

This approach has a significant drawback: it loses information. Consider the following data:

```
1,sensor-内
2,sensor-ょ
3,sensor-へ
```

The output would just strip the kanji, so there would be three elements containing `sensor--`. If that's no good, decide what kind of transformation is needed for the non-ASCII characters. Convert values to plain hex? Skip those altogether? Transliterate to Latin alphabet?

Comment: I keep getting this error when running the line following the import-

Exception setting "data": "The property 'data' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can
be set."

I don't mind losing information on these non-English characters (also wanting to keep commas, punctuation, etc.). Thanks so much for helping me out though, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @JsDart It means your CSV has different column names from my sample. Change `$_.data` to whatever your column's name is.